# Delete an object property with Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object

Is it possible to delete a key with `Object.assign()` instead of setting the value to `undefined` in the following example?

I'm using `.filter()` to go through some items. When there is a match I want to add/change the x-property value and delete the y and z properties (instead of setting them undefined).

```
files.forEach(file => {
    this.setState({ 
        items: this.state.items.filter(item => item.id === file.id ? Object.assign(item, { x: 'x', y: undefined, z: undefined }) : item) 
    });
})
```

Comment: How about `this.state.items.filter(item => item.id === file.id ? { x: 'x'} : item)` ?

Comment: No, delete a key with Object.assign()  is not possible, you can just overwrite it. to delete it you have to do it explicitly

Comment: Just FYI, first argument of `Object.assign` is target. So it mutates `item` which is a bad practice

Comment: Why are you using `filter()` and not `map()` your function inside filter is not returning a boolean which is confusing.

Comment: Simply add the three lines of code you were trying to *smart-off*. Your code will be clearer, and you'll be happy when you'll get back to it in a few months.

Comment: Please approve my answer if you liked my efforts

Answer (score 2):

It is not, check out what the official polyfill does, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill):

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  // Must be writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true
  Object.defineProperty(Object, "assign", {
    value: function assign(target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
      'use strict';
      if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);

      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[index];

        if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
          for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
            // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
              to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
}
```

No exploitable functionality where you would delete a key.

---

You are going to need an explicit `delete`, like:

```
const updateMatch = (item, file, add, unset) => {

    if(item.id !== file.id)
        return item;

    unset.forEach(key => {

        delete item[key];

    });

    return Object.assign(item, add);

} 

files.forEach(file => {
    this.setState({ 
        items: this.state.items.filter(item => updateMatch(item, file, { x: 'x' }, ['y', 'z'])) 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try like below

```
var jbt = {
    "name": "uday",
    "age": "25"
}
console.log("Before Change--->", jbt);
jbt = Object.assign({}, delete jbt.age, jbt);
console.log("Afetr Change--->", jbt);
```

console result

```
Before Change---> { name: 'uday', age: '25' }
Afetr Change---> { name: 'uday' }
```

For your case try like below

```
files.forEach(file => {
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.filter(item => item.id === file.id ? Object.assign({}, delete item.y, delete item.z, item) : item)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While it won't let you delete via `Object.assign`, you can use ES6 destructring to help with this in a clear, clear way:

```js
let file = {id: 12}
let items = [
    {id: 1, x: 1, y:2, z: 13},
    {id: 12, x: 3, y:6, z: 23},
    {id: 13, x: 2, y:9, z: 33},
    {id: 14, x: 4, y:12, z: 43}
]
items = items.map(item => {
    let {y, z, ...obj} = item
    return item.id === file.id ? Object.assign(obj, { x: 'x'}) : item
}) 
console.log(items)
```

Comment: I think the goal is to actually mutate the original items too. Not just a copy. (but I might very well be very wrong)